# PHP/MySQLi - Combining for and while

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

I'm attempting to combine two pages into one for simplicity, however to do so, I need to find a way to combine a for() loop from one page with a while() loop from the other page, so that they both work in the same way.

This is what they currently are:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
```

and

```
while($widget = $grabWidget->fetch_array()) {
```

As you may see, the for() loop does not loop through a MySQLi query, but rather an array of values which are identical to that of what is also in a database.

The second while() loop grabs a set of identical values from the database. However they both must stay on their current bases.

My question is, can both loops be combined into one, while still being able to loop through individual database *and* array elements?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: As requested, here are both the usages for the loops.

```
if($grabWidget = $db->query("SELECT * FROM editor_widgets"))
{
    while($widget = $grabWidget->fetch_array())
    {
        $id = $core->input($widget[1]);
        $coords[0] = $core->input($widget[4]);
        $coords[1] = $core->input($widget[5]);
        $temp = $core->input($widget[2]);

        $content_out = $core->output($widget[3],true);
```

and

```
if(isset($_POST['widgets']))
{
    $widget = $_POST['widgets'];
    $count = count($widget);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        $id = $core->input($widget[$i][0]);
        $content_in = $core->input($widget[$i][1]);
        $coords[0] = $core->input($widget[$i][2][0]);
        $coords[1] = $core->input($widget[$i][2][1]);
        $temp = $core->input($widget[$i][3]);

        $content_out = $core->output($widget[$i][1],true);
```

The new simplified page must have the ability to loop through from either an array OR a MySQLi query. So basically, I want to use the for() loop and have it *also* work with MySQLi

Comment: i don't know why you'd want to do that but you can just increment `$i` inside the `while`, then use that `$i` to traverse the array

Comment: Both pages contain the exact same code, whereas one of them loops through an AJAX request for grabbing an array of elements. Whereas the second page simply grabs this array of elements from the database table, so I'm trying to find a way to simplify this process into one page.

Comment: still vague on my side, maybe you could post both loop usages

Comment: @Ghost original post has been updated.

Comment: so basically, this will all trigger when called upon an ajax request? would they yield the same data? of course if you use the answer below they would have to be lined up correctly (the row result set and the sub array in the for part)

Comment: Sorta. So the file will use a $_GET or $_POST method. If the $_GET method is used, it will run the MySQLi query, whereas if the $_POST method is used, it will use an array of values from AJAX. However I do not want to have a for() *and* while() query, but rather one that will work with whichever method is used.

Comment: oh i see, so now i know why you want to combine those, actually here's the idea, you could just use a foreach in this case, the main thing here is, you must make sure that both, `$_POST` array values and `$_GET` fetch db values are identical, then put them in the final container, then traverse it with just a loop. you just need one loop, just make sure that they will share the exact same structure so that when they are fed inside a loop, the operations inside would still be the same

Comment: @Ghost yeah that's the type of thing I need. However I'm having trouble working out how the MySQLi query would work in such a case. How would you loop through each mysqli row by using a for() loop?

Comment: well yes you still could move the pointer of the current row using `data_seek($i)` inside the for loop, i can't give an answer here since i won't be able to test it so answering here is just like shooting in the dark, i don't have datasets to test with, actually there is two parts, one make sure that the array in your `for` and `$_POST` value widget should be the same, then two: the operations inside the loop, i don't think they are the same. `$widget[$i][2][0]` and then `$widget[2]` on the other loop.

Comment: data_seek()! That looks like exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. As for the $widget[$i][2][0], I'm going to fix those up now. I have a few workarounds for those :) Thanks!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66620/discussion-between-zuc0001-and-ghost).

Answer (score 0):

Add an interator `$i` thats in while thats it.

```
$i=0;
while($widget = $grabWidget->fetch_array()) {
++$i;
// YOUR CODE
}
```